# difference between org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest and org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I am confused with `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest` and `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`

I was deploying my java application with tomcat 5 by specifying catalina jar in my pom.
Now, I'm using tomcat 7 and I deleted the catalina jar from the pom. But, my request is always initialized with `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade` instead of others.

I cleaned the project and server many times, but the same thing happens.

Do you any idea about this problem ?